# PHP script to search mysql database doesn't return result

Tags: php, mysql

Following the code I wrote. This doesn't return any values, even though the table has  the keywords.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty");
mysql_select_db("mis", $conn);
$coursename=$_POST['coursename'];


$sql = "SELECT *
FROM course 
WHERE coursename='$coursename'".
"ORDER BY coursename";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{ 
echo $row['coursename'];
};

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` immediately after your `<?php` and see if you get any error messages from your browser.

You should be able to track down the root cause of your problem.

Good luck with your coursework (i guess ;).

Comment: @lc. Wow. Never knew that. Learn something new everyday. Thanks for the share! :D

Comment: @VihangaGamage Cool. Good luck with it! And you just learned a way how to debug your program! Hope that helps your further development.

Comment: @cychoi Sure thing. The closing single-quote counts as a delimiter so a space is optional. Same with parentheses. Though I generally do like to put spaces so a human can read it more easily.

Comment: I'd also suggest `display_errors true` and `display_startup_errors true` with `ini_set();`. Plus the Zend Coding Style guide. `$var = " ... '$blarg' ...";` is so bad it hurts in the eyes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is case-sensitivity. MySQL identifiers are not case sensitive unless you enclose them in backticks. However, PHP array indexes *are*.

Therefore if you have a column named `CourseName`, the following query *will* work:

```
SELECT *
FROM course
WHERE cOuRSEnaME = 'foo'
ORDER BY courSEnAmE
```

But, referencing it in PHP as `$row['coursename']`, `$row['cOURsENamE']` or any other differing combination will not work, as these all refer to *different* keys. You must use `$row['CourseName']`.

See also: [PHP array, Are array indexes case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511230/php-array-are-array-indexes-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "SELECT *
 FROM course 
 WHERE coursename='$coursename'".
 "ORDER BY coursename";
```

Your code is good but it is much better to use concatenate the string and the variable so it is easily interpreted and also I wanna point out that there is no space before your `ORDER BY` statement  that can cause an error, so make sure there are spaces between them `coursename = '" . $coursename . "' ORDER BY`. See the full query below

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
  FROM course 
  WHERE 
  coursename = '" . $coursename . "' ORDER BY coursename";
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two lines and what problem does changing the code in this way solve?

Comment: Thanks @Backtrack , lc. I understand if youre expert on this language but the obvious question has the obvious answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM course 
        WHERE coursename='" . $coursename . "'
        ORDER BY coursename";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['coursename'];
    }
} else {
    echo "given coursename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: someone is trolling here.. I am voting up to remove that downvoted.. Please help mine.. thanks

Comment: still  the  same error persists,when i run it on the  browser,no results are shown

Comment: No troll here. You should add an explanation as to what the mistake is in the OP's code. Your snippet frankly does nothing different.

Comment: And now after the edit your code is very hard to read and I have no idea what "show link" means.

Comment: @lc. now its fine with the explanation as you mentioned

Comment: when this code runs,just the blank browser page is displayed still

Comment: @VihangaGamage Can you kindly show your full code ... how  your passing the value to SQL query that is form action