# What's wrong with my php login form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

```
    <?php 


    $connector = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw"); // open sql connection
mysql_select_db("dnhsdb",$connector);

    $i = @$_POST['uId']; 
    $d = @$_POST['pass']; 

        if (isset($_POST["btnLog"]))
    {
     $resultID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT", $connector);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($resultID);
    if($i == $row['username'] && $d == $row['pass'])
{
echo "Welcome Userid " . $row['username'] . "!";
 header('Location: form18dnhs.php');
}
else
echo "Wrong Id/Password";

    }
```

Error message says:

```
Undefined index: username in C:\Users\Chad\Desktop\MAIN_php_project\USBWebserver v8_en\root\DNHS\login.php on line 21
Wrong Id/Password
```

Comment: LINE 21 code:  if($i == $row['username'] && $d == $row['pass'])

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP script to search mysql database doesn't return result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118857/php-script-to-search-mysql-database-doesnt-return-result)

Comment: it is saying that your index "username" is probably not matching the column name of your database or you don't have exact column...make sure you have the same column name that you are fetching from.. posting the table structure might be good help..:D

Comment: Wow... so much wrong with your code.  Start with, mysql_ functions are deprecated... should be using pdo or mysqli.  Stop using @ suppression.  You do a SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT when it should be SELECT * from ACCOUNT WHERE uId = $i AND pass = $d (although these should be bound variables).  As it is now, you fetch one row and "hope", I guess that you get the right one?  It's a bit of a mess and seems like you don't understand sql too well, or how the client library actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code:

1. You should not use the `@` operator. It is used to suppress errors, warnings, notices, and so on. When you get an error, warning or notice you should never ignore them; instead you should figure out why you are getting them and then fix it. Suppressing them is like building an airplane and just ignoring every security inspector. It is not a good thing.
2. The `mysql` extension has been deprecated and should not be used. See the warning in the [documentation](http://php.net/mysql_connect). You should instead use one of the [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) extensions.
3. Whenever you access an array you have to make sure that the index/key exists. This is done using the [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) function. This applies to normal arrays and the `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc. arrays. If you do not check that an index is set then you will get errors.
4. You should never assume that a `$_POST` or `$_GET` index is set just because another index is set. In other words, just because `$_POST["btnLog"]` is set, it does not mean that `$_POST['uId']` and `$_POST['pass']` are set, too. This is a quite common error, even for experienced developers (it is easy to overlook), but that is not an excuse.
5. In SQL databases it is rare that you select everything inside a table. You should use the `WHERE` clause to narrow down the search, such as `SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = $i AND pass = '$d'`. You should read a few [SQL](http://google.com/search?q=sql%20tutorial) [tutorials](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/) to learn how SQL works.
6. When you get your SQL sorted you should probably also learn a bit about security (i.e. about [sanitizing and validating](http://php.net/filter) input and using [prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) [statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)). Search for "SQL security" or something along that line and you should find a lot of reading material.
7. Echoing something before a `header('Location: ...')` redirect does not make sense. Redirect responses may contain a body but it is ignored; the browser just redirects the browser to another page without showing the body.
8. Finally, the way in which you compare the passwords it appears that you are storing password in the clear (as plaintext). If someone gains access to your database they will have access to the credentials of all your users. Some people tend to use the same password for many different websites, which means that **you** will have compromised those accounts as well. This is quite serious. You need to read up on [securing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200417/encrypting-a-password-column-in-a-sql-database/18200554#18200554).

Good luck.

Comment: This ia a far better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined index: username" means there's no `username` index in your `$row` variable.

I think you want to be using [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) not `mysql_fetch_row`.  `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns a row as an associative array (where you use the string indices to get specific fields).

Also, the `mysql_` library has been [deprecated since PHP 5.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).

And finally,

## *Do not store passwords in plain-text!!!*

Comment: Sir @jonathan reinhart I've also tried using mysql_fetch_assoc but the if statement doesnt execute and instead the else statement executes even if the username and password input was correct please help :D

Comment: You need to debug your code yourself, we can't do it for you. `echo` and `print_r` are your friends; use them to verify that variables have the values you *think* they do.

Comment: @Chad, these are the least of your issues.  Your entire approach is wrong... selecting the entire Account table and going through looking for the user is at best inefficient.  Your code logically won't work because you don't even loop through the results, but even if you did, it wouldn't work without changing things.