# Generate PHP array from MySQL with key value from "id" column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
ID        TEXT        PARENTID
20        Item1        null
23        Item2        20
27        Item3        20
80        Item4        27
```

What I want is to retreive this data in an array like this:

```
Array ( 
[20] => Array ( [text] => Item1 [parentID] => ) 
[23] => Array ( [text] => Item2 [parentID] => 20 ) 
[27] => Array ( [text] => Item3 [parentID] => 20 ) 
[80] => Array ( [text] => Item4 [parentID] => 27 )
);
```

Notice that the key values represent the value of the id column in the table.

I have tried makin an array inside a mysql loop (I am still in the process of learning MySQLi, and hopefully it'll stick pretty soon but this example is in the old MySQL):

```
$hent_folder = mysql_query("SELECT id, text, parentID FROM folders");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hent_folder))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
```

The result here of course generates "automatic" key values and not the values from the ID column as wanted plus it puts the ID column as a part of the inside array.

Is there a way or workaround to succeed here?

I hope someone can lead me in the right direction...

----- EDIT ------

I have replaced

```
$array[] = $row;
```

with

```
$array[$row['ID']] = $row;
```

But it still does not return the above wanted result. It returns this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 20 [text] => Item1 [parentID] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 23 [text] => Item2 [parentID] => 20 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 27 [text] => Item4 [parentID] => 20 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 80 [text] => Item4 [parentID] => 27 )
);
```

Comment: `$array[$row['ID']] = $row;`

Comment: `$array[$row['id']] = $row;`

Comment: if your new to php then my first suggestion is to drop mysql_* function and to look into pdo and mysqli

Comment: the OP is actually already doing that as said in his actual question gentlemen, `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` aren't very different but again, not everyone is equally experienced otherwise we wouldn't need SO

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand - OP wasn't doing that according to the original question, that has been added since..... though the original gave no indication of case in column names, and this is a now a case-sensitivity issue

Comment: @MarkBaker, in that case my apologies. I should have checked before posting my comment in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is doable as an associative array.

All you have to do is change

`$array[] = $row`

to

`$array[$row['ID']] = $row`

You need to make sure that the `ID` column in your database is unique so that the associative array doesn't overwrite keys (in which case only the last record with duplicate ID's would remain)

### EDIT (19-11-2015)

Also about your 'mysql loop' - it's just a regular PHP `while` loop that loops through records given by either `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` functions. You're looping through the returned result from executing an sql statement on the database which just fetches and formats rows for you in a certain way.

MySQL and MySQL*i* are two different things but the SQL they use is no different (except for maybe prepared statements?).
Learning SQL is what you're going to do and to execute it you're going to use `mysqli_*` from now on since `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

I just wanted to point those things out to clear out some confusion you might already have or will have in the future. :)

For more reading on mysqli read the [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), it's all a bit complex if you're just starting but that's fine - understand what you can and work to understand what you can't.

---

### EDIT 2 (19-11-2015)

the indexes in your `$row` array are [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511230/php-array-are-array-indexes-case-sensitive) so `ID` and `id` are something different entirely. one will add up to an `undefined index` error.

I noticed in your output that the `id` key is actually *lowercase* so I would try changing to that.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Sidney - I have tried this, but unfortunately this does not work. It returns everything from the table but still with the array key values from 0 to 3. My ID column is setup as an integer with auto increment and unique so I think that should do it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong then?

Comment: This is definitely the way to make it work @MazeyMazey, I am failing to understand why it wouldn't since I've done this a billion times. Could you update your question with the **new** code and the **new** error output perhaps?

Comment: Hi @Sidney - There are no errors. It works, but the value given for each array-result is numbered from 0 and up instead of the value of my id column in my table.
Result:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => Item1 [parentID] => )
I wanted it to output:
Array ( [20] => Array ( [text] => Item1 [parentID] => )

Comment: @MazeyMazey I understand your problem completely, it just baffles me - it **shouldn't** happen unless there's some bug in PHP concerning this which I highly doubt

Comment: This is probably a dumb question @Sidney, but there is not a difference in viewing the result?
I do this: print_r(array_values($array));
This displays the numerical values from 0 and up.
I have just tried on a different domain and with a different database, different table and data (same PHP though) and still the same output with the key value.

Comment: `print_r($array)` should show you the keys that are used, not just an index however if you want to be sure try echoing a key that is supposed to exist so if there's a row with an id of 20, **after** the loop do a `print_r($array[20])` to see if you get an undefined index, if you do get one I can't really help any further due to being at work..

Comment: Thanks @Sidney - I did try and implement the code to the project and with the $array[$row['ID']] = $row it worked, eventhough when printed through print_r($array) it displays an indexed set of keys.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MazeyMazey it is weird that it prints the indexes tho but alright, we got there! Good luck with your project :)

Comment: @sidneyliebrand  op is calling `array_values` for some unknown reason,  so he is stripping the array keys himself

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this result easily using PDO. It has a fetch mode called `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` and when combined with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` will produce you the array that you want.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4", $user, $pass, [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, text, parentID FROM folders');
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Multidimensional array. 
// main array by id with text and parent in secondary array
// tryed going by the second diagram

$arr = array();
$hent_folder = mysql_query("SELECT id, text, parentID FROM folders");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hent_folder))
{
    $arr[$row['id']]['text']     = $row['text'];
    $arr[$row['id']]['parentID'] = $row['parentID'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian - this does display the content inside the array correct without the ID, but still the array key values are numerically made and not the ID values unfortunately...

Comment: theres gotta be something else wrong, aside from me usin mysqli instead of mysql I've used this exact looking code a hundred times

Comment: you mentioned that your ids are auto increment, perhaps they are the same values as the array keys?

Comment: It does work @Ian, I mean there is no error in it, but the first array value is just not the ID value:  [0] => Array ( [text] => Item1 [parentID] => ) The [0] should have been [20].

Comment: I have checked this - the values in the ids in the column is 1,5,59,60,61,62 etc. and not the 0,1,2,3 as displayed when printing the array.

Comment: I'm stumped, if the answer doesn't pop in this thread before you find it kindly leave me a comment of what exactly was wrong. Thanks. @MazeyMazey

Answer (score -1):

Below code can be used to produce an array of the ids from SQL response :

```
$ids_array = array();

foreach($idsFromDb as $row)
{
    $ids_array[] = $row['id'];
}

echo print_r($ids_array[0]) ;
```

Comment: This code will produce an array of the ids, but that is not what the question asked for.