# How to return and print a specific method?

Tags: php, arrays, class, methods, instance

I have 2 methods in class.

The first method get `$id` to retrieve 3 parameters of a specific item via webservice. It's a webservice of a Real Estate system. I will use these 3 parameters to find related items.

**So far, all is ok.**

My problem is to return data of `resemblant()` method.

I instantiate the `object`, I sent the `$id` to **features** method and I registered the **attributes**.

The `$get` attribute return information but `$similar = $obj->resemblant()` has no return.

I'm learning.

> How to return the ***data*** that is inside the method `resemblant()` in `$similar`?

```
<?php 

require("Acesso.class.php");

class Semelhantes extends Acesso
{
    public function features($id)
    {
        $postFields  = '{"fields":["Codigo","Categoria","Bairro","Cidade","ValorVenda","ValorLocacao","Dormitorios","Suites","Vagas","AreaTotal","AreaPrivativa","Caracteristicas","InfraEstrutura"]}';
        $url         = 'http://danielbo-rest.vistahost.com.br/'.$this->vsimoveis.'/'.$this->vsdetalhes.'?key=' . $this->vskey;
        $url           .= '&imovel='.$id.'&pesquisa=' . $postFields;

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array( 'Accept: application/json' ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch); 
        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        /**
         * Paramentros para filtrar semelhança
         * @var [type]
         */
        $fcidade    = str_replace(" ", "+", $result['Cidade']);
        $fdorms     = $result['Dormitorios'];
        $fvalor     = $result['ValorVenda'];

        return array(
            'cidade' => $fcidade, 
            'dorms' => $fdorms, 
            'valor' => $fvalor
        );

    }

    public function resemblant()
    {
        $get = $this->features($id);
        return $get['Cidade'];
    }

}

/* Chamando as funções em outra parte do sistema */
$obj        = new Semelhantes;
$features   = $obj->features(2);
$similar    = $obj->resemblant();
```

**Very thanks**

Comment: `var_dump($result)` in `features` is it populated

Comment: Please dont amend your question after you receive a valid answer to your question. It makes the answer look unnecessary and stupid. The main point of SO is to provide searchable questions and answer for others to make use of if they have similiar problems

Comment: Ok @RiggsFolly, very sorry !!!

Comment: You instantiated the object and called the `features()` method passing it with `$id` and you expect the returned value get populated in `$get` in `resemblant()` method where in the scope of that method `$id` is undefined?

Comment: @Dagon var_dump return data ... http://puu.sh/mmemu/5679f4382a.png

Comment: Your intentions are not clear hear! `resemblant()` has no idea what `$id` is as you do not either pass it as a parameter OR save it as a class property when you call `features(2)` can you let us know if you want `resemblant()` to work with the parameter sent to `features()` or work independantly

Comment: My intention is to send the data from `features()` to `resemblant()` and print `resemblant()` ... thanks for our help **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options to fix the issues in here

First you can change `resemblant()` to receive a parameter

```
public function resemblant($id)
{
    $get = $this->features($id);
    return $get['cidade'];   // case of variable fixed also
}
```

and call it with the same paramter as `features()`

```
/* Chamando as funções em outra parte do sistema */
$obj        = new Semelhantes;
$features   = $obj->features(2);
$similar    = $obj->resemblant(2);
echo $similar;
```

Or you can save the parameter when passed to `features()` as a property and reuse it in `resemblant()`

```
protected $last_id;

public function features($id)
{

    $this->last_id = $id;

    // other existing code

}

public function resemblant()
{
    $get = $this->features($this->last_id);
    return $get['cidade'];   // case of variable fixed also
}
```

And then call these methods like you had originally

```
/* Chamando as funções em outra parte do sistema */
$obj        = new Semelhantes;
$features   = $obj->features(2);
$similar    = $obj->resemblant();

echo $similar;
```

Comment: This is a very good solution @RiggsFolly ... thanks for your help and  
tolerance with me. I don't speak english but I try.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function you set the array like this:

```
return array(
   'cidade' => $fcidade, 
   'dorms'  => $fdorms, 
   'valor'  => $fvalor
);
```

In the second function, you access the value like this:

```
return $get['Cidade'];
```

Notice the **cidade** and **Cidade**? Different case. This is what you meant to do:

```
return $get['cidade'];
```

You can read more about case sensitivity in arrays here: [PHP array, Are array indexes case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511230/php-array-are-array-indexes-case-sensitive)

Comment: echo `$similiar` will do it

Comment: The `case sensitivity` seems not the problem but I corrected this **:)**

Comment: Well, it was one *one* of the problems then. Glad you got it figured out :)