# Wordpress: Different Menus on pages

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have an About page with an about menu. but, I also want a Resources page with its own menu. However, the about menu seems to show up on the Resources page regardless of how I edit the template file.

functions.php

```
function hab_register_menu() {
     register_nav_menu( 'header-menu', __( 'Header Menu' ) );
     register_nav_menu( 'about-menu', __( 'About Menu' ) );
     register_nav_menu( 'resources-menu', __( 'Resources Menu' ) );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'hab_register_menu' );
```

page-resources.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <main id="content" class="container">
     <div id="main">
         <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' );    
            the_content();
         endwhile; ?> 
     </div> <!-- #main -->
     <aside id="sidebar">
         <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
             'Theme_location'   =>  'resources-menu',
             'menu_class'           =>  'v-menu',
             'container'                =>  false
         ) );
         ?>
     </aside>   <!-- #sidebar -->
 </main>    <!-- #content .container -->

 <?php get_footer();?>
```

[Website](http://hab.kailikameoka.com/resources/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, PHP array keys are [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511230/php-array-are-array-indexes-case-sensitive). Try updating your array from:

```
'Theme_location'   =>  'resources-menu',
```

to:

```
'theme_location' => 'resources-menu',
```

I don't think your theme is actually parsing a `theme_location` due to that, so it uses it's [default usage functionality](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#usage) of falling back to the first registered menu that's not empty.

If/since that doesn't work there are a few other things you can try. [`register_nav_menu()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) actually has a plural sister function [`register_nav_menus()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus). You could try registering them that way (it's the typical way to register multiple menus since around WP 3.0):

**ANSWER [Asker's notes]**
I guess there's a limit to how many times you can call the singular version of the function.

```
function hab_register_menu() {
   register_nav_menus( array(
       'header-menu'    => __( 'Header Menu' ),
       'about-menu'     => __( 'About Menu' ),
       'resources-menu' => __( 'Resources Menu' )
   ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'hab_register_menu' );
```

If that doesn't do anything either, you could look at adding the `menu` argument to [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters):

```
'menu' => 'resources-menu'
```

If *that* doesn't work, are you sure WordPress is finding your [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) correctly? It should be finding `page-{slug}.php` based on the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy), provided the slug for your page is actually `resources`. If not, consider adding a File Header, namely adding the following to the top of your `page-resources.php` file:

```
/**
 * Template Name: Resources
 */
```

And then picking the new "Resources" page template in the sidebar of the page editor.

You could also simple modify `page.php` (or your theme's equivalent) to pull in the menu based on the current page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <main id="content" class="container">
        <div id="main">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' );    
                the_content();
            endwhile; ?> 
        </div> <!-- #main -->
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <?php
                if( is_page( 'Resources' ) ){
                    $theme_location = 'resources-menu';
                } else if( is_page( 'About' ) ){
                    $theme_location = 'about-menu';
                } else {
                    $theme_location = 'header-menu';
                }

                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => $theme_location,
                    'menu_class'     => 'v-menu',
                    'container'      => false
                ) );
            ?>
        </aside> <!-- #sidebar -->
    </main> <!-- #content .container -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to include all the cases I can think of about _why_ it may not be loading